# Proof that product of submanifold is submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I was given the following definition of submanifold:
Let *M* be a smooth manifold. If $N\subset M$ and $\mathscr{i}:N \to M$ (inclusion mapping) is an embedding, then *N* is a submanifold of *M*.

Now how can I prove that if $N_i$ is a submanifold of $M_i$, for *i*=1,2, then $N_1 \times N_2$ is a submanifold of $M_1\times M_2$ ?

Comment: Define the obvious inclusion mapping and show that it is an embedding? (I suppose you mean $N_1\times N_2$ instead of $N_1*N_2$, as I'm not sure what else the latter would mean).

Comment: Yes, bad formatting, I fixed it.

Comment: That was the idea, you're right. But I'm not really sure how to show that this constructed inclusion mapping is an embedding.

Comment: You could find slice charts in the codomain; you could show it's a topological embedding and that it's an immersion.

Comment: Okay, that's probably something I wasn't introduced yet. At the moment I only know that embedding is immersion+submersion (immersion is the map which pushforward is injective, submersion is the map is surjective)

Comment: That's not what an embedding is. That's a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: @MikeMiller Yeah, it was my bad lecture notes :) My mistake. So I figured out what to do. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, seems like I figured it out how to do it. I read in Lee book "Introduction into Smooth Manifolds" about the k-slices, but I'll give it a try it with just knowing the definition of embedding.

Denote $\mathscr{i_i}:N_i\to M_i$, $i=1,2$, the inclusion mappings. Since $N_i$ are submanifolds, then $\mathscr{i_i}$ are immersions and homeomorphisms onto their images. That means, that $\mathscr{i_1}\times\mathscr{i_2}: N_1\times N_2 \to M_1\times N_2$ are also homeomorphisms onto its image. So we only need to show that $\mathscr{i_1}\times\mathscr{i_2}$ is an immersion, or $(\mathscr{i_1}\times\mathscr{i_2})_*$ is an injection. Let's take some tangent vectors $v=(v_1,v_2)\in T_{p_1}N_1\oplus T_{p_2}N_2$ (we can do that since $T_{p_1,p_2}N_1\times N_2 $ is isomorphic to $T_{p_1}N_1\oplus T_{p_2}N_2$), such that $(\mathscr{i_1}\times\mathscr{i_2})_*v=0$

$$0=(\mathscr{i_1}\times\mathscr{i_2})_*v=(\mathscr{i_1}_*v_1,\mathscr{i_2}_*v_1)$$
This means that both $\mathscr{i_1}_*v_1=0$, $\mathscr{i_2}_*v_2=0$, and since $\mathscr{i_i}$ are immersions, then $v=0$.

And since tangent mappings are linear, then $(\mathscr{i_1}\times\mathscr{i_2})_*$ is injective, which ends the proof.

Comment: Good! If you're looking to be a teeny bit more careful, you might say more carefully why $i_1 \times i_2$ is a homeomorphism into its image.